# How to make easy_install expand a package into directories rather than a single egg file?

Tags: python, django, setuptools, easy-install, egg

How exactly do I configure my setup.py file so that when someone runs easy_install the package gets expanded into \site-packages\ as a directory, rather than remaining inside an egg.

The issue I'm encountering is that one of the django apps I've created won't auto-detect if it resides inside an egg.

**EDIT:** For example, if I type `easy_install photologue` it simply installs a `\photologue\` directory into site-packages.  This the the behaviour I'd like, but it seems that in order to make that happen, there needs to be at least one directory/module within the directory being packaged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You add `zip_safe = False` as an option to setup().

I don't think it has to do with directories. Setuptools will happily eggify packages with loads of directories in it.

Then of course it's another problem that this part of Django doesn't find the package even though it's zipped. It should.

Comment: Django doesn't find it because of the way its auto_discover() command works.